# Call another module with passing its command line parameter from my module using argparse in python

Tags: python, module, wrapper, argparse

I searched and tried following stuff but could not found any solution, please let me know if this is possible:

I am trying to develop a python module as wrapper where I call another 3rd party module with its .main() and provide the required parameter which I need to get from command line in my module. I need few parameter for my module too.

I am using argparse to parse command line for calling module and my module. The calling parameter list is huge (more than 40) which are optional but may require anytime who will use my module. Currently I have declared few important parameters in my module to parse but I need to expand with all the parameter.

I thought of providing all the parameter in my module without declaring in add_argument. I tried with parse_known_args which also require declaration of all parameter is required.

Is there any way where I can pass on all parameter to calling module without declaring in my module? If its possible please let me know how it can be done.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 4):

Thanks hpaulj, mguijarr and mike,

I was able to resolve the issue with all above inputs, like following:

My module:

```
import sys
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='something')
parser.add_argument('--my_env', help='my environment')

if __name__=='__main__':
    args,rest = parser.parse_known_args()
    rest_arg = ['calling_module.py']
    rest_arg.extend(rest)
    sys.argv = rest_arg
    import calling_module
    calling_module.main()
```

Answer (score 2):

Does this scenario fit?

Module B:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse....
def main(args):
    ....
if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = parser.parse_args()
    main(args)
```

Module A

```
import argparse
import B
parser = argparse....
# define arguments that A needs to use

if _name__=='__main__':
    args,rest = parser.parse_known_args()
    # use args
    # rest - argument strings that A could not process
    argsB = B.parse_args(rest)
    # 'rest' does not have the strings that A used;
    # but could also use
    # argsB = B.parse_known_args() # using sys.argv; ignore what it does not recognize
    # or even
    # argsB = B.parse_known_args(rest)
    B.main(argsB)
```

Alternate A

```
import argparse
import B
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[B.parser], add_help=False)
# B.parser probably already defines -h
# add arguments that A needs to use

if _name__=='__main__':
    args = parser.parse_args()
    # use args that A needs
    B.main(args)
```

In one case, each parser handles only the strings that it recognizes.  In the other A.parser handles everything, using the 'parents' parameter to 'learn' what B.parser recognizes.

Comment: hpaulj, I dont wanted to define A's argument again as its huge list and I wanted that to work as its define in A (3rd Party module).

Answer (score 0):

Provided that you are calling third-party modules, a possible solution is to
change **sys.argv** and **sys.argc** at runtime to reflect the correct parameters for
the module you're calling, once you're done with your own parameters.

Comment: Remember to do this BEFORE importing the wrapped module.

Comment: I tried this too, in my case the parameter passed for 3rd party module also taken from my module command line. means if 3rd party module accepts 'a', 'b', 'c' parameter, I am getting these value from command line from my module along with my required parameter.